# I want to edit my message as it calculates the Bot Latency

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```
if (message.content.startsWith('h#ping')) {
        message.channel.send('*Calculating...*').then((pingCalc) => {
            const ping = pingCalc.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
            message.reply(`Ping: ${ping}ms`)
        })
}
```

Instead of replying ping, I want to edit the *Calculating...* part for the 'ping' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Message` object has an [edit](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) method. So `<Message>.edit()` would edit the message. Since you are resolving the promise after sending the message using `then()`, inside the then function instead of `message.reply()` you could just do,
`` pingCalc.edit(`Ping: ${ping}ms`) `` would edit the sent message.

```
if (message.content.startsWith('h#ping')) {
        message.channel.send('*Calculating...*').then((pingCalc) => {
            const ping = pingCalc.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
            pingCalc.edit(`Ping: ${ping}ms`)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Message#edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) to edit the message.

```
pingCalc.edit(`Ping: ${ping}ms`)
```

The whole code:

```
message.channel.send('*Calculating...*').then((pingCalc) => {
  const ping = pingCalc.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
  pingCalc.edit(`Ping: ${ping}ms`)
})
```

---

I would recommend renaming `pingCalc` to `pingCalcMessage` for clarity.